# Json wont arrive

Tags: android, json, api, android-studio, retrofit

My friend coded an API and i have to code the frontend for it on Android. But the json won't arrive. I know that my code works because i testet it on 3 diffrent testers and his api also works. He also testet it a few times. But if i send something to no data will arive. The request arrives but not the data. The response also works but it always says that the Strings are null. I host the api on my own computer. Could it be, that the Virtual Device can't send anything to the pc it is hosted on? I hope someone can help me.

here is my code:

MainActivity

```
 public void post(String pswd, String name){
    TextView textViewResult = findViewById(R.id.responses);
    Post post = new Post(name,pswd);

    HttpLoggingInterceptor loggingInterceptor = new HttpLoggingInterceptor();
    loggingInterceptor.setLevel(HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.BODY);

    OkHttpClient okHttpClient = new OkHttpClient.Builder()
            .addInterceptor(loggingInterceptor)
            .build();

    Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl("http://localhost:5000")
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
            .client(okHttpClient)
            .build();

    API api = retrofit.create(API.class);

    Call<Post> call = api.createPost(post);
    call.enqueue(new Callback<Post>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<Post> call, Response<Post> response) {
            if(!response.isSuccessful()){
                textViewResult.setText("Code: " + response.code());
                return;
            }
            Post postResponse = response.body();
            String content = "";
            content += "Code: " + response.code() + "\n";
            content += "token: " + postResponse.getToken() + "\n";
            content+= "msg: " +postResponse.getMsg();

                Endcontent = content;
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<Post> call, Throwable t) {
            Endcontent = t.getMessage();

        }

    });

}
```

Api:

```
import java.util.List;

import retrofit2.Call;
import retrofit2.http.Body;
import retrofit2.http.FormUrlEncoded;
import retrofit2.http.GET;
import retrofit2.http.POST;

public interface API {
    @GET("posts")
    Call<List<Get>> getPosts();


    @POST("api/gen_token")
    Call<Post> createPost(@Body Post post);


}
```

and the Post:

```
public class Post {
    private String name;
    private String pswd;
    private String token;
    private String msg;

    public Post(String name, String pswd) {
        this.name = name;
        this.pswd = pswd;
    }

    public String getPswd() {
        return pswd;
    }
    public String getMsg(){
        return msg;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public String getToken() {
        return token;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

check string name and string pswd value where you have assigned them